# Error with putting SELECT SUM into an IF statement

Tags: sum, mysql-error-1064

I encounter an error with code 1064 in my SQL statement but I cannot see where it is wrong.

I want to sum all the ETCS of all modules that a student have take part in. I have tried and the SELECT SUM statement is correct an return the sum.

However when I put it in an IF statement, error code 1064 is return.

The info on number of ETCS of each module is stored in table module_details.
The info of modules taken by student is stored in table student_module.

```
IF(SELECT SUM(module_etcs) AS total_etcs     
FROM student_module   
INNER JOIN module_details     
ON student_module.module_id = module_details.module_id     
WHERE student_module.student_id = '2222') = 10    
THEN    
INSERT INTO alumni_details(student_id,alumni_status)    
VALUES('2222','S123');    
END IF;
```

The value return by the SELECT SUM is 10.
But put in the IF statement cause error.